# 7z is renaming the nested .gz file while extracting iso file. How to stop renaming it?

Tags: linux, iso-image, 7-zip

I am trying to extract ISO file using 7z.
Let's say we have below folder structure

```
centosserver/x/16890efb08ba2667b3cfd83c4d234d5fabea890e6ed2ade4d4d7adec9670a9a5-primary.xml.gz
```

But I noticed the strange thing. When I extract ISO using mount commnd

`mount -o loop CentOS.iso /mnt/iso`

nested folder structures .gz file is not getting renames but when I extract using 7z command

`7z x -y CentOS.iso -o/centosserver`

it is getting rename to centosserver/x/16890efb08ba2667b3cfd83c4d234d5fabea890e6ed2ade4d4d7adec9670a9a5 (I have confirmed it using md5sum and content. it is not getting extracted just getting rename ). While extracting zip 7z is mantaining the structure. I have gone through many 7z documents to specify the correct flag to not to rename file but unfortunately no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that, but I suspect your ISO's layout and/or filesystem is a hybrid of two formats. Tools that work with ISO files can choose which format to prefer and all choices are valid. Apparently 7z makes a different choice than the loop mount. There was a question on this site about a CD having different contents on Windows and macOS, you can try to find it.

Comment: Those are exactly 80 characters. Probably not a coincidence. Perhaps take a look at the ISO image's various ISO extensions like Joliet and Rock Ridge.